# exe file in Qt Quick 2.2 can't load corectly

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a program in Qt Quick 2.2 for display images and videos by transition. I have windows 32 bit and Qt 5.3.1 (msvc2010 Opengl) on my computer.I set build configuration to release and build my program and add [this](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8121389192/pic.png) dll files to release folder (qwindows.dll is in the platforms folder). When i run exe file on my computer (in my computer installed directx and codecs of media player and  Qt 5.3.1) the program works good but when i run exe file on another computer (in this computer install directx 11 and codecs of media player but does't installed any version of Qt) it can does transition between images good but it couldn't show videos. i use dependency walker and it show me [this](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8128603650/error.png). and use windeployqt that its results brings in first link (by folder dlls). where is the problem?

Comment: why any one doesn't request to me???

Comment: Because it's a non-trivial question and you may need to wait until someone ready it who faced the problem before.